# How to start new activity from another activity without button click in android

Tags: java, android

I made a simple game, where whenever my object reaches end of the screen current activity stops and another activity stars.

I have created a simple boolean method called `collisionDetection()` which checks whether an object is hitting the end of the screen or not. However, I don't know where I should use that method `collisionDetection()` .

Should I check for collision at onResume? And when collision is detected, how to start another activity and stop the main one?

My class for **first activity**

```
public class ZmijicaCrtanje extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{

ZmijicaSV zmija;
private static int score=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    zmija=new ZmijicaSV(this);
    zmija.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(zmija);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zmija.pause();
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    zmija.resume();

}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean up=zmija.sp.isUp();
    boolean right=zmija.sp.isRight();
    boolean down=zmija.sp.isDown();
    boolean left=zmija.sp.isLeft();


    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if(up) {
                zmija.sp.setUp(false);
                zmija.sp.setRight(true);
                update();
                break;
            }

            if(right) {
                zmija.sp.setRight(false);
                zmija.sp.setDown(true);
                update();
                break;
            }

            if(down) {
                zmija.sp.setDown(false);
                zmija.sp.setLeft(true);
                update();
                break;
            }
            if(left) {
                zmija.sp.setLeft(false);
                zmija.sp.setUp(true);
                update();
            break;
        }


    }
        return true;
    }

public void update()
{
    score++;
}
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}

}
```

public class ZmijicaSV extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

```
private boolean Collision;
Thread t=null;
Pravougaonik pr;
SurfaceHolder holder;
boolean isRunning=false;
SnakeParts sp;
ZmijicaCrtanje zc;
public ZmijicaSV(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder=getHolder();
    pr=new Pravougaonik(context);
    sp=new SnakeParts();
    zc=new ZmijicaCrtanje();
    Collision=false;
}

public void run()
{
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
     while(isRunning)
     {

         if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
             continue;
         }
         Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
         c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         sp.Draw(c);
         pr.onDraw(c);
         sp.update();
         drawText(c);
         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

         try {

            t.sleep(50);

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}

public void resume()
{
    isRunning=true;
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void pause()
{
    isRunning=false;
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    t=null;

}

public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("Score:"+zc.getScore(),getWidth()-230,getHeight()-25,paint);
}

public boolean checkCollision()
{
    if((sp.getHeadX()<-1)||(sp.getHeadX()>getWidth())||(sp.getHeadY()>getHeight())||(sp.getHeadY()<-1))
        Collision=true;
    return Collision;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Put the `collisionDetection()` method in your `public void update()` method like

```
 public void update()
 {
   score++;
   collisionDetection();
 }
```

And when collition is detected in `collisionDetection()` start next activity by **Intent** like

```
Intent next=new Intent(this.class,your_class_for_secondactivity.class);
startActivity(next);
```

Comment: Just tried it...it works...well part of it.The problem is, the new activity starts only when I click the screen(assuming the object is already hitting the edge of the screen).I want to it to immediately start new activity once objects collides with end of screen without me having to perform click action.The problem lies in the update() method as it is only called in onTouch method.Any possible fixes to this?Where should update( ) be called as well?
Edit:The object is constantly moving to the right edge of the screen once main activity starts

Comment: can your object reach the end even when you are not touching the screen?? i see the object moves when you touch it @igorcar1994

Comment: My apologies if I didn't explain correctly.Class ZmijicaSV is using a SurfaceView and I have created a simple rectangle.It also has simple thread which updates x-coordinate of it.So, the object is constantly moving even when I'm not touching the screen.I'm using OnTouch method for something else.

Comment: include the thread in your question. As per i understand now you should detect the collision from thread. @igorcar1994